# Why is (we haven't bought such thing) incorrect?

Tags: phrase-usage

I encountered this problem when I was doing a course in Duolingo. It marked me wrong to write

> We haven't bought such thing.[1]

The correct one according to Duolingo is:

> We haven't bought such a thing.[2]

I read the comment section. There was a native American commented that it's wrong to write [1]. He/she also added that a native speaker would likely to say either:

> We have bought no such thing.[3]

Or

> We haven't bought such things.[4]

Since it's a standalone sentence, I don't know what **thing** refers to. Supposing the **thing** is a bottle of wine, does that mean I could say [2] or [3]? Also, if it's two bottles should I use [4]? In addition to that, what if it's an uncountable noun like furniture? Why do [2] and [3] make a difference?

Comment: *native American*? That's quite specific. Do you mean a native English speaker from the US? *native Americans* are the Indigenous peoples of the US.

Comment: @AIQ idk. He/she only stated that he/she is a native american. No further explanation on his/her comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To understand the sentence, try taking out "such." You could also flip it from negative to positive:

> We bought **a** thing.

The article is needed here because "thing" is a common noun.

> We bought **such a** thing.

This really means "a thing *such as* this," or "*like* this." The article is still needed.

---

> We bought such things.

**Yes**, in this case you need no article because now the things are plural. You mention bottles of wine; to use that without "such", we might have:

> - We bought **a** bottle of wine, OR
> - We bought bottles of wine.